# linking and sending form values to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

My html code:

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("","","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
// echo('Connected with Mysql');
}
@mysql_select_db("a", $con);// connect to database db_name
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$email=$_POST['email']; 
 $pass=$_POST['pass']; 
$sql_query="INSERT INTO formdata (email, pass) VALUES('$email', '$pass')";}
?>
```

Database name: `mysql` 
Table name: `formdata`

Why it is not working? in second line I used 'local host' first but I was receiving error so I removed it.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: (1) Do not suppress error messages. `@mysql_select_db("a", $con);` (2) Show us all the HTML for the form. (3) Define "not working"

Comment: You cannot mix MySQL APIs. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` --- Plus, your conditional statement will fail. It's based on looking for your submit button being named `Submit` which it isn't.

Comment: I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 2):

1. You use the `mysqli_` API to connect to your database and then test for errors and try to select a database with the `mysql_` API. Pick one and stick to it. (Don't pick `mysql_` it is deprecated).
2. You only run the form handling code if there is a `Submit` data item in the submitted data. You have no form control with `name="Submit"` so that will never happen.
3. Your form handling code expects there to be `email` and `pass` data in the submitted data but your form does not have fields with those names.
4. Constructing an SQL query as a string and storing it in a variable is insufficient to do anything to your database. You have to actually sent it to the database server. That would use [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) with your current approach, but you should switch to [prepared statements](/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)